# twitter source to hive sink using flume

Tags: twitter, hive, schema, flume

I am trying to connect twitter source to hive sink using flume.
I have my property file given below

```
# Naming the components on the current agent.
TwitterAgent.sources = Twitter
TwitterAgent.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks = k1

# Describing/Configuring the source
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type = org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource
#TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type = com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerKey = xxx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerSecret = xxx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessToken = xxx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessTokenSecret = xxx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.keywords = kafka, flume, hadoop, hive

# Describing/Configuring the sink

TwitterAgent.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.type = memory
TwitterAgent.sinks = k1
TwitterAgent.sinks.k1.type = hive
TwitterAgent.sinks.k1.channel = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks.k1.hive.metastore = thrift://xxxx:9083
TwitterAgent.sinks.k1.hive.database = sample
TwitterAgent.sinks.k1.hive.table = tweets_twitter
#TwitterAgent.sinks.k1.hive.partition = user_location
TwitterAgent.sinks.k1.useLocalTimeStamp = false
TwitterAgent.sinks.k1.round = true
TwitterAgent.sinks.k1.roundValue = 10
TwitterAgent.sinks.k1.roundUnit = minute
TwitterAgent.sinks.k1.serializer = DELIMITED
TwitterAgent.sinks.k1.serializer.delimiter = "\t"
TwitterAgent.sinks.k1.serializer.serdeSeparator = '\t'
#TwitterAgent.sinks.k1.serializer.fieldnames =user_friends_count,user_location,user_email

# Describing/Configuring the channel
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.type = memory
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity = 100000
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity = 1000
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.byteCapacity = 6912212

# Binding the source and sink to the channel
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks.k1.channel = MemChannel
```

I am not creating any database or table in hive here. Should i need to create database name, table name, partition column, field names?? before starting the agent ??
If so where should i get the schema of twitter streaming data??

I am starting the flume agent using this below command

```
bin/flume-ng agent --conf ./conf/ -f conf/twitter_hive.conf Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,console -n TwitterAgent --classpath "/usr/hdp/2.6.3.0-235/hive-hcatalog/share/hcatalog/*":"/usr/hdp/2.6.3.0-235/hive/lib/*"
```

Where should i get the schema of twitter data to create hive tables, to be mention in twitter.conf property file

Answer (score 0):

`HiveSink` was introduced in version 1.6 and as per the [documentation](http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#hive-sink), yes the metastore, database name and the table name are mandatory. The partition part however is optional as flume can create the missing partitions.

As for the schema for twitter, it seems to be a problem some others have also faced and I found [this link](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/11/analyzing-twitter-data-with-hadoop-part-3-querying-semi-structured-data-with-hive/) quite useful (You may have already come across this). It mentions some of the data structures available in hive that you may need to work with data coming in JSON format. You may however need to alter some of the bits and pieces for your scenario but this should give you a good start.

I hope this helps.